# How to use Google Colaboratory Form Dropdown in code cell that begins with an exclamation mark

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I've looked into forms, but they only work for very basic code (such as print, or setting up a config). I am trying to run a python program which means I have the cell code as !python3 .py -flags arguments

The arguments are what I'd like to change, however even with a dropdown form selection, I can't get the code to understand that the argument is from a form, instead of taking the literal text which doesn't when I change the dropdown.

Here's the cell's code:

```
Section = "tracks" #@param ["tracks", "newalbums", "justreleased", "pop", "rock", "electronic", "country", "hiphop", "rnb", "kpop", "classical", "jazz", "latin", "holiday"]
!python3 redsea.py -a TV explore atmos Section
```

When I run this code, it runs "!python3 redsea.py -a TV explore atmos Section" not "!python3 redsea.py -a TV explore atmos tracks" which is what I have selected for the parameter.

I hope this explanation shows why the forms option is NOT working for me. I would appreciate further help.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god I posted this question too quickly...

Here's the updated code with a **single character change** that fixed it...

```
Section = "tracks" #@param ["tracks", "newalbums", "justreleased", "pop", "rock", "electronic", "country", "hiphop", "rnb", "kpop", "classical", "jazz", "latin", "holiday"]
!python3 redsea.py -a TV explore atmos $Section
```

Yep, just add a $ before the part you wanted to be from the form.